# 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: virtualPath on ViewStart.cshtml'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]I am experience this exception on MVC application, on viewStart.cshtml and i do have that path there as specified under my Views folder on my project and path. The logic is as below;

```
@{
    var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();

    string layout = "";
    if(controller == "Admin")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    }else
    {
         Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    }
    Layout = layout;
```

Comment: You should post the full exception here if you expect to receive any help. Without that, it is impossible to even guess what might be going on

Comment: Are you mixing `Layout` and `layout` in the `if` statment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Layout correct, either:

```
    string layout = "";
    if(controller == "Admin")
    {
        layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    }
    else
    {
         layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    }
    Layout = layout;
```

or

```
    if(controller == "Admin")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    }
    else
    {
         Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    }
```

Comment: If i am doing that way, i notice i am getting the code on the browser

Comment: Shown as text, or what do you mean?

Comment: I end up figure it out, the problem was mixing the two layout, first layout is a string object and other Layout, made those changes  i can able to load the login page.